# How to execute the command NPM init in the nodejs file

Tags: node.js, npm

How to execute the command `npm init` in the nodejs file? I want to use `node. / index.js` to execute the command. But what should I do if the command interacts with the user?

This code is directly stuck, and the subsequent question and answer cannot be carried out.I hope users can fill in the information normally

```
let exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("npm init")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow users to fill in the questionnaire via the CLI, consider using the `child_process` module's [`spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) method instead of [`exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback).

#### *Nix (Linux, macOS, ... )

For example:

**index.js**

```js
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

spawn('npm', ['init'], {
  shell: true,
  stdio: 'inherit'
});
```

**Note:** After the user has completed the questionnaire this example (above) creates the resultant `package.json` file in the current working directory, i.e. the same directory from where the `node` command invoked `index.js`.

However, If you want to ensure that `package.json` is always created in the same directory as where `index.js` resides then set the value of the [`cwd`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) option to [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_dirname). For example:

```js
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

spawn('npm', ['init'], {
  cwd: __dirname,        // <--- 
  shell: true,
  stdio: 'inherit'
});
```

---

#### Windows

If you are running node.js on Windows then you need to use the following variation instead:

**script.js**

```js
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

spawn('cmd', ['/c', 'npm init'], {  //<----
  shell: true,
  stdio: 'inherit'
});
```

This also utilizes the `spawn()` method, however it starts a new instance of Windows command shell ([cmd](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)). The `/c` option runs the `npm init` command and then terminates.

---

#### Cross-platform (Linux, macOS, Windows, ... )

For a cross platform solution, (i.e. one that runs on Windows, Linux, macOS), then consider combining the previous examples to produce the following variation:

**script.js**

```js
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const isWindows = process.platform === 'win32';
const cmd = isWindows ? 'cmd' : 'npm';
const args = isWindows ? ['/c', 'npm init'] : ['init'];

spawn(cmd, args, {
  shell: true,
  stdio: 'inherit'
});
```

Comment: you are awesome

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there doesn't need to be any user input you could do:

```js
let exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("npm init -y")
```

Comment: I hope users can fill in the information normally